# Socket.io - Polling fails with 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nodejitsu

I'm running a single Socket.io server ( **2.0.3** ) .

In the client side i'm trying to allow only polling mode.

```
io.connect(url, {
   "transports": ['polling']
})
```

The problem is that polling fails and throws:

`"code":1,"message":"Session ID unknown"`  response. And the client get disconnected.

i have tried to place **node-http-proxy** server in front of the socket.io server. So the client connect to node-http-proxy server. This solved the problem, but i don't understand why...

Can someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix it ???

Comment: Are you using Sticky load balancing?